# Создания одиночного тега JQ

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, svg, frontend

Нужно создать одиночный тег stop через JQ. А потом вставить его в linearGradient. Делаю все это след. способом:

```
GradStart = document.createElement('stop'),
GradEnd = document.createElement('stop');
```

Потом накидываю некие атрибуты на данные stop:

```
GradStart.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
GradStart.setAttribute('stop-color', startGrad);
GradEnd.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
GradEnd.setAttribute('stop-color', endGrad);
```

Потом добавляю туда куда нужно:

```
Fill.appendChild( GradStart );
Fill.appendChild( GradEnd );
```

Дело в том, что jq создает сразу двойные теги. (`<stop></stop>`). А мне необходимо сделать одинарный тег (`<stop АТРИБУТЫ />`). А с двойными тегами svg градиент не хочет работать :с

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь создать svg-элемент с помощью `createElement()`, но это не правильно, тк им создают html-теги. Для svg используйте [`createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS):

```js
Fill=document.getElementById('linear-gradient')


GradStart = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");
GradEnd = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");

GradStart.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
GradStart.setAttribute('stop-color', 'gold');
GradEnd.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
GradEnd.setAttribute('stop-color', 'teal');

Fill.appendChild( GradStart );
Fill.appendChild( GradEnd );
```

```html
   
<svg>
  <!-- Градиент -->
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
  </linearGradient>

  <!-- Фигура с градиентной заливкой -->
  <rect fill="url(#linear-gradient)"
        width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Кстати, `createElementNS()` тоже создает двойные теги, так-что это тут не при чем. Тем более, что по стандарту, тег `<stop>` может содержать внутри другие теги